# C# windowservice file watcher takes only first file

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have a problem with FileWatcher in Window Service. I set up incoming folder which is watched by the fileWatcher but it takes only first file. When I paste to the folder new file then nothing happen. 
Somebody help me? Please

```
namespace Equalizer_Service
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            ServiceBase.Run(new Service1());
        }

        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            fileSystemWatcher1.Path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WatchPath"];
            Library.WriteErrorLog("Window service was started");
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            Library.WriteErrorLog("Window service was stopped");
        }

        private void fileSystemWatcher1_Changed(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            GetPaths.getPaths();
            GenerateXML.generateXML();
            Excel_Chart.KillExcel();
            Library.WriteErrorLog("Job was done after file was changed");
        }

        private void fileSystemWatcher1_Created(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            GetPaths.getPaths();
            GenerateXML.generateXML();
            Excel_Chart.KillExcel();
            Library.WriteErrorLog("Job was done after new request was added");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not see the code that initializes the fileSystemWatcher1. Like the EnableRaisingEvents property and the NotifyFilter property.

Comment: It is done in designer - I took the item from toolbox and there I set up appopriate settings.

Comment: Are you sure your service is still running when you paste the second file? I ask this question because I cannot see any useful code in the event handling procedures (except for logging), just some crappy looking lines which could perhaps crash...

Comment: Even if it is done in the designer you can post that code so we can see what you mean with 'I set up appopriate settings'